# Modern language for ad-hoc XML queries?

Tags: xml

I have to do some data mining on XML documents lately. Most of it ad-hoc, i.e, I don't have the schema of the documents in advance, and I only run the query a couple of times. Some example queries are "how many elements have this sub-element value greater than 0" or "per some kind of elements, what is the sum of the values of some of their sub-elements".

Running such queries in Java is awkward because (a) Java DOM processing is really cumbersome, and (b) I only need to run these queries a for a few times, not as a part of an application.

What is a recommended and currently-supported query language and tool for this scenario? Preferably interactive, free/open-source, and does not require storing the document in a database in advance (although it's an option).

Comment: LINQ, according to me, can do the job very well! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linq

Comment: I removed the inappropriate tag data-mining. There is no data-mining in the question, this is just about XML querying. No advanced analysis happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need XQuery. It is purpose made to easily query XML, as can be read from a quote on [XQuery homepage](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/):

> XQuery is replacing complex Java or C++ [XML processing] programs with a few lines of code.

I use the open-source program [BaseX](http://basex.org/) to easily query (large collections of) XML files. It also features a nice interactive visualization of the XML structure.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a description of XQuery.

Example queries

```
count(//element[sub-element gt 0])

//some-element/sum(sub-element)
```

Actually both of those are XPath 2.0, which is a sub-set of XQuery 1.0, but you will probably want XQuery 1.0 sooner or later, and it is more widely implemented than XPath 2.0, so go for it. There are plently of XQuery processors that work in a Java environment, with or without an XML database. My own Saxon product is one example.